# how to loop through multiple arrays inside an array and filter a value from it-Javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm using EXTJS framework for my code.
below is my array structure:

```
data = [{
  id: 22,
  rows: [{
    id: "673627",
    name: "ABS",
    address: "536street"
  }, {
    id: "333",
    name: "TEST$$",
    address: "536street"
  }, {
    id: "999",
    name: "TEST$$",
    address: "536street"
  }]

}, {
  id: 33,
  rows: [{
    id: "899",
    name: "TES",
    address: "536street"
  }, {
    id: "333",
    name: "TEST$$",
    address: "536street"
  }, {
    id: "999",
    name: "TES673",
    address: "536street"
  }]

}]
```

Now I want to filter the name from this array, whose value I'm comparing with say "TEST$$".
I'm doing this;

```
Ext.each(data, function(item) {
  filter = item.rows.filter(function(name) {
    return name.name === "TEST$$";
  }, this);
}, this);
console.log(filter);
```

In this case, it returns only 1 match, where as I have 3 matches for this particular value. It returns the match from the last item in the data array and hence I dont get all the matching values, any idea how this can be looped to get all values matching?

thx!

Comment: You're overwriting `filter` each time through the loop. When the loop is done, the variable will only contain the last value. Put `console.log(filter)` inside the loop.

Comment: `console.log(filter)` within `EXT.each` loop ;)

Comment: Or make `filter` an array, and use `filter.push()` instead of `filter =`.

Comment: You talk about *returning*, but this code doesn't return anything, it just prints to the console.

Comment: What is the actual result you want to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're *reassigning* the `filter` variable on every iteration over the `data` array:

```
filter = item.rows.filter(function(name) {
  return name.name === "TEST$$";
}, this);
```

On the last iteration, there is only one match, the one with `id` of `333`, so that's the only one that you see after running the `Ext.each`. Try pushing to an external array that *doesn't* get overwritten instead:

```
const testItems = [];
Ext.each(data, function(item) {
  const filtered = item.rows.filter(row => row.name === "TEST$$")
  testItems.push(...filtered);
});
console.log(testItems);
```

Note that there's no need to pass along the `this` context.

Another option is to `flatMap` to extract all `rows` to a single array first:

```
const output = data
  .flatMap(({ rows }) => rows)
  .filter(({ name }) => name === 'TEST$$');
```